# Why does my own login view with my own User model in Django doesn't work?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have created my own user model in Django:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=False)
    token_num = models.IntegerField(_('token count'), default=0)
    money_num = models.IntegerField(_('money count'), default=0)

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')
```

So then i decided to do my own login view. Here it is:

```
def login(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/main/")
else:
    form = LoginForm()
return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is my LoginForm:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    user_email = forms.EmailField(max_length=255)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password')
```

And my login.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Login</h2>
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    <p>
      {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
      {{ field }}
      {% if field.help_text %}
        <small style="display: none">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
      {% endif %}
      {% for error in field.errors %}
        <p style="color:red">{{ error }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
    </p>
    {% endfor %}
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

And here is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^log/$', views.login)
]
```

So the problem is that when I enter all data at login page the user doesn't log in and I'm not redirected to the main page. The login page is reloading and that's all.
P.S I have already created 1 user with email and password. This user `is_active` is set to `True` (1)

Comment: did you set AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py ? That should reference your custom model.

Comment: Yes,, I did it.

Comment: Use `logging` and check what is failing. Can you log in to admin with that account?

Comment: Yes, I can. I'll try to use logging, ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is in your `LoginForm`.

It is not ModelForm, so you can remove the Meta class.

And your email field is called `user_email` but in the login view, you try to get `email` from the POST params.

Try to get the consistent name and you should be able to log in.

Answer (score 1):

Your LoginForm has the field `user_email` but your code access `email` from request.POST; these need to be the same.

Note, you should probably check `form.is_valid()` and get the data from `form.cleaned_data`, rather than direct from the POST. Also note, your form is (correctly) not a ModelForm so the inner Meta class and its contents are irrelevant.